# Apache Pig: Filter one tuple on another?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I want to run a Pig script by splitting out two tuples (or whatever it's called in Pig), based off of criteria in `col2`, and after manipulating `col2`, into another column, compare the two manipulated tuples and do an additional exclude.

```
REGISTER /home/user1/piggybank.jar;

log = LOAD '../user2/hadoop_file.txt' AS (col1, col2);

--log = LIMIT log 1000000;
isnt_filtered = FILTER log BY (NOT col2 == 'Some value');
isnt_generated = FOREACH isnt_filtered GENERATE col2, col1, RANDOM() * 1000000 AS random, com.some.valueManipulation(col1) AS isnt_manipulated;

is_filtered = FILTER log BY (col2 == 'Some value');
is_generated = FOREACH is_filtered GENERATE com.some.calculation(col1) AS is_manipulated;
is_distinct = DISTINCT is_generated;
```

Splitting and manipulating is the easy part. This is where it gets complicated. . .

```
merge_filtered = FOREACH is_generated {FILTER isnt_generated BY (NOT isnt_manipulated == is_generated.is_manipulated)};
```

If I can figure out this line(s), the rest would fall in place.

```
merge_ordered = ORDER merge_filtered BY random, col2, col1;
merge_limited = LIMIT merge_ordered 400000;

STORE merge_limited into 'file';
```

Here's an example of the I/O:

```
col1                col2            manipulated
This                qWerty          W
Is                  qweRty          R
An                  qwertY          Y
Example             qwErty          E
Of                  qwerTy          T
Example             Qwerty          Q
Data                qWerty          W


isnt
E
Y


col1                col2
This                qWerty
Is                  qweRty
Of                  qwerTy
Example             Qwerty
Data                qWerty
```

Comment: Please provide example input and output.  I'm not clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: There you go. See if that helps explain it better.

Comment: Anyone? I need this ASAP, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure quite what you need, but I believe you can reproduce your input and output with the following (untested):

```
data = LOAD 'input' AS (col1:chararray, col2:chararray);
exclude = LOAD 'exclude' AS (excl:chararray);

m = FOREACH data GENERATE col1, col2, YourUDF(col2) AS manipulated;
test = COGROUP m BY manipulated, exclude BY excl;

-- Here you can choose IsEmpty or NOT IsEmpty according to whether you want to exclude or include
final = FOREACH (FILTER test BY IsEmpty(exclude)) GENERATE FLATTEN(m);
```

With the `COGROUP`, you group all tuples in each relation by the grouping key.  If the bag of tuples from `exclude` is empty, it means that the grouping key was not present in the exclude list, so you keep tuples from `m` with that key.  Conversely, if the grouping key was present in `exclude`, that bag will not be empty and the tuples from `m` with that key will be filtered out.